# Need assistance manipulating database values from opencart admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

I am working on creating an extension for my opencart installation.  I am currently running OpenCart V1.5.5.1.  Below you will find the code and procedure I have followed to get to this point.  Hopefully someone can help me find what else I need to get this part of the project done.

The first thing that I did was add two columns to the product table in my opencart database.  These columns are as follows:

goal_activate tinyint(1) (Looking for possible values of 0 or 1)

sales_goal INT (Any integer)

I also used the following code to add the necessary text and selection boxes for the admin panel to display the controls.  The idea here is to have a selection box for each product that will allow our staff to turn on the sales goal (goal_activate) and set the value of the goal (sales_goal).

```
    <file name="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->data['entry_quantity'] = $this->language->get('entry_quantity');]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $this->data['entry_goal_activate'] = $this->language->get('entry_goal_activate');
        $this->data['entry_sales_goal'] = $this->language->get('entry_sales_goal');
        ]]></add>
    </operation>                
</file>
<file name="admin/language/english/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[$_['entry_quantity']         = 'Quantity:';]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $_['entry_goal_activate']     = 'Activate Sales Goal<br/><span class="help">Activate the sales goal thermometer for this product.</span>';
        $_['entry_sales_goal']     = 'Set sales goal<br/><span class="help">Sales goal is set in total units sold.</span>';
        ]]></add>
    </operation>                
</file>

<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[<td><?php echo $entry_minimum; ?></td>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <td><?php echo $entry_goal_activate; ?></td>
            <td><select name="goal_activate">
              <?php if ($goal_activate) { ?>
              <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
              <option value="0"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <option value="1"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
              <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_sales_goal; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sales_goal" value="<?php echo $sales_goal; ?>" size="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>                
</file>
```

Now, everything looks great in the admin panel, and my database columns all have proper data types and default values.  All I am missing is the code that will actually alter my database values based on user input with the controls created.  I believe that I am missing some additions to the controller files for admin/controller/catalog/product.php, I'm just not sure what I need to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I apologize if anything in my question is not to form or lacking in information, this is my first post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database handling is done by the `model` layer of Opencart's MVC-L framework. So you have to do some changes like this as well:

```
<file name="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = '" . $this->db->escape(html_entity_decode($data['image'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");         
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET your_field_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['your_field_1']) . "', your_field_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['your_field_2']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" .  (int)$product_id . "'");
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: This information was very useful for me.  I posted an additional answer below that has more code which I had to include.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer submitted by Tibor B., I had to include the following code:

```
<file name="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">  
<operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->request->post['minimum'])) {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        if (isset($this->request->post['goal_activate'])) {
        $this->data['goal_activate'] = $this->request->post['goal_activate'];
            } else if (!empty($product_info)) {
                $this->data['goal_activate'] = $product_info['goal_activate'];
            } else {
                $this->data['goal_activate'] = 0;
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        if (isset($this->request->post['sales_goal'])) {
        $this->data['sales_goal'] = $this->request->post['sales_goal'];
            } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
                $this->data['sales_goal'] = $product_info['sales_goal'];
            } else {
                $this->data['sales_goal'] = 0;
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
```